# Windows Metro apps have wrong icon in search UI

Tags: windows-10, modern-ui, windows-search

When I search for any app in the Windows 10 search, it has the same wrong icon (this is just an example):

[image: screenshot of wrong icon]

When having the app open or when looking at it in different places (start menu, taskbar, the app itself), the icon is fine (these are just examples of places I could look):

[image] [image]

How can I resolve this? I did nothing quirky with the metro app system (like modifying/installing/uninstalling via PowerShell or by using external tools). This is in a fresh Windows 10 Pro setup that is *one* day old.

I already tried:

- Rebuilding the Windows search index completely
- Rebooting
- Installing an app and uninstalling it again from the Windows store
- Giving "Everyone" full permissions to `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to System > Advanced System Settings > Performance >Settings

You should see the option for "**Show thumbnails instead of icons.**"

Click to enable.

A quick reboot and a few minutes, you should see the Windows Store icons reappear. At least this was the fix for me.

Comment: Yep, this also overlaps with the "Best appearance" setting I talked about above (It sets the setting in your answer)

Comment: This did not work for me: neither did activating "Show thumbnails instead of icons", nor did selecting "Best appearance". I did reboot and wait about 20 minutes. Windows v1709.

Comment: @bers In my case it was far more difficult to solve - see if https://superuser.com/a/1292334/236537 helps

Comment: Didn't work for me...

Answer (score 1):

First, thank you for your posting!

I believe in MY case it was additionally necessary to delete the following App Icon Cache directory:

`c:\Users\ExampleUserName\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\AppIconCache\100\`

**Replace `ExampleUserName` with your real involved username.**

**Remove only the directory `100`. It will be recreated automatically later.**

PS: I believe I have this hint with folder `100` from the following site (it's in german language):

https://www.deskmodder.de/wiki/index.php/Suche_Suchfunktion_funktioniert_nicht_richtig_Windows_10#Suche_zeigt_keine_oder_falsche_Icons_an