# Broken icons in Windows when doing a search

Tags: windows-10, icons, windows-store-app

Whenever I perform a search in Windows, I get broken icons for some apps. They mostly seem to be Windows store apps (calculator, calendar, mail, camera).

Anyone knows how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: maybe clearing the icon cache can solve it?

Comment: I tried this: www.howtogeek.com/232779/how-to-rebuild-a-broken-icon-cache-in-windows-10/. But there are two files that I cannot delete, I get an "access is denied" message.

Comment: which files can't you delete?

Comment: `iconcache_idx.db` is one and the other I'll tell you when I get home :)

Comment: have you opened the cmd and closed Explorer as told in the guide?

Comment: Yes, I also opened the cmd as administrator and rebooted my computer

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me crazy, but this fix solved it for me. I really don't recall checking that box, though.
Anyway, I unchecked it and APPLIED TO ALL FOLDERS, rebooted. First try it didn't work and them it started working (probably caching).

[Solved Broken Icons source](http://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/53919-broken-windows-10-store-app-icon-search-result.html)

> Problem solved I had to uncheck "Always show icons, never thumbnails" in folder option --> View Tab and restart computer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was settings being synced between machines via my Microsoft account.

I tried all sorts of fixes, including repairing Windows Store Apps, SFC, clearing icon and thumbnail cache files, etc. I tried switching the *System > Advanced System Settings > Performance > Settings > Show thumbnails instead of icons*. I tried *Explorer > File > Change folder and search options > View > Always show icons, never thumbnails*. I tried disabling the syncing of *Other Windows settings* under *Settings > Accounts > Sync your settings*.

The only way I was able to fix the issue was:

1. Turn of settings syncing with your Microsoft account on all Windows installs. (*Settings > Accounts > Sync your settings*)
2. Go to https://onedrive.live.com/win8personalsettingsprivacy and click the *Remove* button to delete the cloud copy of all settings
3. Convert your Window account to a local user account, thereby unlinking it from your Microsoft account (*Settings > Accounts* click the *Sign in with a local account instead* link)
4. Create a new Windows account on the machine, first as a local-only account so you can pick your username (*Settings > Accounts > Family &   other people* then *Add someone else to this PC*).
5. Log into the new account and go to *Settings > Accounts* to link it up to your Microsoft account
6. Move settings and files from your old local account to the new account
7. Remove your old local account

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Creating a new account is more like a workaround then a proper fix :(

Comment: @RicardoAmaral Unfortunately I found no way to resolve the issue other than to create a new account and move the data over after purging the stuff from OneDrive. I spent quite a while online searching and trying various methods. This was the only one that allowed me to keep my Microsoft account-based login and fix the issue. All of the others that worked just involved creating new local login accounts no tied to a Microsoft account.