# Icons broken in search results of Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, icons, windows-search

Basically, it looks like this-

[image: Broken Icons]

I tried doing [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/232779/how-to-rebuild-a-broken-icon-cache-in-windows-10/) but it did not work out.

Is there any way this could be solved?

Comment: Do the shortcuts work?

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes it does.

Comment: The answer given at http://superuser.com/questions/1085605/windows-metro-apps-have-wrong-icon-in-search-ui worked for me.